# A monotonically decreasing function and inequality

Tags: calculus

> Can it be shown that when $$\mathbb{R}_0^+\colon=[0,\infty[$$
>   for all
>   $$x\ge0$$
>   that
>   $$\ln(x+1)\le x$$
>   so far I have shown
>   $$f{'}(x)=  \frac{1}{1+x}-1<0$$
>   hence function is monotonically decreasing and has a global maximum at $$x=0$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Simply add this line to your last line of proof:

$f(x) \leq f(0) \to \ln(1+x) - x \leq 0 \to \ln(1+x) \leq x$.